# Find and count all rows inside a specific div

Tags: javascript

I want to find a count all div's with class row inside a specific div

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

I tried with this but its not working...

```
var div = document.getElementByClassName('input_field_wrap');
var myrows = div.getElementsByClassName('row');
alert(myrows.length);
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element `var div = document.getElementByClassName('input_field_wrap')[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
var myrows = document.querySelectorAll('.input_fields_wrap > .row');
alert(myrows.length);
```

Comment: He does not need to at all, he just needs to understand document.getElementsByClassName returning a collection. Maybe elaborate on that.

Comment: @Lain but then he also needs to use css parent selector.

Comment: Well, it is alright.. just stating that he needs to use querySelectorAll() is kind of a bold statement.. and he still does not know why his code did not work in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Use `document#querySelectorAll`, and check for the rows, which are children of the parent selector:

```js
var numOfRows = document.querySelectorAll('.input_fields_wrap > .row').length;
console.log(numOfRows);
```

```html
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Why your code isn't working:**

```js
//var div = document.getElementByClassName('input_field_wrap');
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('input_fields_wrap'); // typo in getElementsByClassName - missing s in Elements

//var myrows = div.getElementsByClassName('row'); 
var myrows = div[0].getElementsByClassName('row'); // div is an array like object, and you want to get the 1st item

alert(myrows.length);
```

```html
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll() always has a length.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myrows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
```

Assuming that `row` class is only present inside the `input_fields_wrap` div. If not, change its name, so you can take use of this very simple method.

Comment: Does not show the actual length tho - which was requested. Could at least point out why the OP code does not work, since he uses the same method.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('row').lenght;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JQuery selector:

```
($("#input_field_wrap").find(".row")).length
```

Simple as that.